# Extracting data from owl file using java,gwt,eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, ontology

I have to display content from the owl file namely the class names.. onto my browser, I am using GWT,eclipse to do so, could some one tell me the following :-
1)how do I integrate the owl file with the eclipse project?

2)How do I run queries from my java project to extract class names from the owl file?

3)Where can I get the protege api to nclude into my project?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could just store your .owl file anywhere inside your project or on any other location on your harddrive. You just provide a path to it, when you load/store it (see code below).
2. Take a look at the [OWLAPI](https://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/), it allows you to load an existing ontology and retrieve all classes from it. Your code could look like this:

   ```
   private static void loadAndPrintEntities() {
       OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
       IRI documentIRI = IRI.create("file:///C:/folder/", "your_rontology.owl");
       try {
           OWLOntology ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(documentIRI);
           //Prints all axioms, not just classes
           ontology.axioms().forEach(a -> System.out.println(a));
       } catch (OWLOntologyCreationException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Rather than trying to integrate the Protegé API into your project, I suggest you write a plugin for Protegé. There are some great [examples](https://github.com/protegeproject/protege-plugin-examples) that should get you started. Import this project into Eclipse, modify the content, build your plugin and drop it into Protegé. That's it, you're ready to go!